# getimagesize error

Tags: php, image, getimagesize

My upload/crop function is working almost how I want it. Except Im having to refresh my page to show the uploaded image..And then when I delete the image using the delete button futher down my code, I get the following 2 errors showing in my header. And the upload form doesn't show up again unless I refresh the page, then the following errors dissapear from view until I delete the uploaded image again.

Here is the two errors and then the code with the getimagesize functions marked as bold.

```
  Warning: getimagesize(imgs/pic7.jpg) [function.getimagesize]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in ----- on line 48

    Warning: getimagesize(imgs/pic7.jpg) [function.getimagesize]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in ------ 42
```

This is the area of the issue with the two errors marked as bold -

```
$id=$_SESSION['id'];
$upload_dir = "imgs";               // The directory for the images to be saved in
$upload_path = $upload_dir."/";             // The path to where the image will be saved
$large_image_name = "pic".$id.".jpg";       // New name of the large image
$thumb_image_name = "cropped".$id.".jpg"; 
$max_file = "1148576";                      // Approx 1MB
$max_width = "500";                         // Max width allowed for the large image
$thumb_width = "100";                       // Width of thumbnail image
$thumb_height = "100";                      // Height of thumbnail image

//Image functions
//You do not need to alter these functions
function resizeImage($image,$width,$height,$scale) {
    $newImageWidth = ceil($width * $scale);
    $newImageHeight = ceil($height * $scale);
    $newImage = imagecreatetruecolor($newImageWidth,$newImageHeight);
    $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($image);
    imagecopyresampled($newImage,$source,0,0,0,0,$newImageWidth,$newImageHeight,$width,$height);
    imagejpeg($newImage,$image,90);
    chmod($image, 0777);
    return $image;
}
//You do not need to alter these functions
function resizeThumbnailImage($thumb_image_name, $image, $width, $height, $start_width, $start_height, $scale){
    $newImageWidth = ceil($width * $scale);
    $newImageHeight = ceil($height * $scale);
    $newImage = imagecreatetruecolor($newImageWidth,$newImageHeight);
    $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($image);
    imagecopyresampled($newImage,$source,0,0,$start_width,$start_height,$newImageWidth,$newImageHeight,$width,$height);
    imagejpeg($newImage,$thumb_image_name,90);
    chmod($thumb_image_name, 0777);
    return $thumb_image_name;
}
//You do not need to alter these functions
function getHeight($image) {
    **$sizes = getimagesize($image);**
    $height = $sizes[1];
    return $height;
}
//You do not need to alter these functions
function getWidth($image) {
    **$sizes = getimagesize($image);**
    $width = $sizes[0];
    return $width;
}
```

Comment: _"No such file or directory"_ - seems pretty clear to me. Print the path to the file you're about to open and see what's wrong.

Comment: That is what I thought.. My path is mysite/imgs/ 

Is it that when the image is deleted off the server its still looking for such image.. As saved images are under $_SESSION['id'];

mysite/imgs/pic".$id.".jpg
mysite/imgs/cropped".$id.".jpg"

Comment: Because its looking for getimagesize(imgs/pic7.jpg) but if I've just deleted it..Its not going to be there..So how would I rectify this. By not deleting and just overwriting the file with a new one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `getimagesize($image)` on deleted image of course should give you error. Check if file exists before calling `getimagesize($image)` with `file_exists($file_path)` function.

Comment: Like this 
`if (file_exists($large_image_location)){
 if(file_exists($thumb_image_location)){
  $thumb_photo_exists = "<img src=\"".$upload_path.$thumb_image_name."\" alt=\"Thumbnail Image\"/>";
 }else{
  $thumb_photo_exists = "";
 }
    $large_photo_exists = "<img src=\"".$upload_path.$large_image_name."\" alt=\"Large Image\"/>";
} else {
    $large_photo_exists = "";
 $thumb_photo_exists = "";
}`

Comment: I took out the delete and just replaced it with the form. This will then overwrite the file so their is something for the function to look to on the server.